# How to enable/disable startup services in Ubuntu?

Tags: server, startup, services

There seems to be no definitive solution for this, either in Ubuntu's official documentation or other sources of information.

In some places systemctl is suggested but I think Ubuntu does not support it for the moment.

Other suggestions include manually creating the links, but I feel there should be a better way. On the other hand there are graphical programs to achieve this, but what about servers without GUI?

In Fedora I don't think this is an issue. You can use chkconfig to add/remove a service from the startup sequence.

The equivalent of chkconfig for Ubuntu seems update-rc.d, but:

```
# update-rc.d modemmanager enable
update-rc.d: /etc/init.d/modemmanager: file does not exist
```

Since Ubuntu is the most used GNU/Linux distribution, I believe there must be a way to do this in the command line with a specific command.

Comment: @lemonslice: If I read correctly, none of the solutions answers my question.

Comment: Sorry I should have asked which version of Ubuntu you are using. 
Also, is `echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/modemmanager.override` working for you?

Comment: First which flavor of Ubuntu are you running?.Is it Xubuntu,Ubuntu GNOME,Ubuntu Mate,Lubuntu or just plain old default Ubuntu.

Comment: @lemonslice: Sorry, I'm using Linux Mint based on Ubuntu 14.04, so it's not the most updated Ubuntu release. The command worked, but is it meant to enable or disable the service? It continued disabled.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? This is for upstart to determine which commands to start at reboot.

Comment: I'm sorry---what a mistake!---, I mixed my workstation with the server that I'm working on: the server release is Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Comment: @lemonslice: ModemManager package changed some time ago, and now it runs modemmanager only when NetworkManager is running. Since I am not running NetworkManager, I have to run modemmanager on my own. So I'd like to `chkconfig modemmanager on`.

Comment: So it is not working with the override file I proposed?

Comment: No, after reboot: `$ cat /etc/init/modemmanager.override
manual
$ service modemmanager status
modemmanager stop/waiting`. Should I replace "manual" with "auto" or so?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26584/discussion-between-joao-m-s-silva-and-lemonslice).

Comment: I think I'll have to run `service modemmanager start` from `/etc/rc.local` which seems a bad and dirty solution...

Comment: First, Mint is off-topic on this site. Mint is its own distribution. This site supports only official flavors of Ubuntu: Ubuntu Studio, Lubuntu, Xubuntu. Second, AFAIK Mint stil uses upstart, so you should use `sudo service modemmanager stop` to stop temporarily, or edit/move the appropriate file in `/etc/init` folder

Comment: @Serg Please read comment from Aug 4 at 15:31. I'm using Ubuntu. So, the conclusion is that there is no command to achieve this, I must tweak /etc/init/modemmanager, right?